# Quarkus to support dynamic rest call

Tags: java, quarkus-rest-client

In quarkus how dynamic rest call can be achieved?

I tried with register rest client, but it is not suggested for passing dynamic based urls

Comment: What do you mean and what have you tried? https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive has several examples including for programmatic calls with a custom URL. What else do you need?

Comment: It's not possible right now. I was facing same issue need to dynamically create url on each request. Solved it by creating new client every time, yes its expensive but works.